# Streamline Google Script for combining multiple CSV to avoid timeout

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am working on a sheet that combines 10 CSV files that are stored in a google folder into one google sheet.  I have been able to run the code previously, but I am starting to run into a lot of time based errors.  I am hoping that someone can help streamline the following code.  I know that I could run this in a loop, but I don't think that would be any faster.

---

```
//Sets Sheets to variable

  var AUG = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Set1.csv").next();
  var Sep1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Set2.csv").next();
  var Sep2 = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Set3.csv").next();
  var Oct1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Set4.csv").next();
  var Oct2 = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Set5.csv").next();
  var Nov1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Set6.csv").next();
  var Nov2 = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Set7.csv").next();
  var Dec1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Set8.csv").next();
  var Dec2 = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Set9.csv").next();
  var Dec3 = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Set10.csv").next();

//Parse String
  var csvAUG = Utilities.parseCsv(AUG.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var csvNov1 = Utilities.parseCsv(Nov1.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var csvNov2 = Utilities.parseCsv(Nov2.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var csvOct1 = Utilities.parseCsv(Oct1.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var csvOct2 = Utilities.parseCsv(Oct2.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var csvSep1 = Utilities.parseCsv(Sep1.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var csvSep2 = Utilities.parseCsv(Sep2.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var csvDec1 = Utilities.parseCsv(Dec1.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var csvDec2 = Utilities.parseCsv(Dec2.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var csvDec3 = Utilities.parseCsv(Dec3.getBlob().getDataAsString());
//Determine Lengths
  var rowset1 = csvAUG.length
  var rowset2 = rowset1+csvSep1.length;
  var rowset3 = rowset2+csvSep2.length;
  var rowset4 = rowset3+csvOct1.length;
  var rowset5 = rowset4+csvOct2.length;
  var rowset6 = rowset5+csvNov1.length;
  var rowset7 = rowset6+csvNov2.length;
  var rowset8 = rowset7+csvDec1.length;
  var rowset9 = rowset8+csvDec2.length;
  var rowset10 = rowset9+csvDec3.length;
  var colset = csvAUG[0].length;

//Start Combines CSV's for Scores
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Raw Scores"));
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.clear();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, rowset1, colset).setValues(csvAUG);
    sheet.getRange(1+rowset2, 1, csvSep1.length, colset).setValues(csvSep1);
    sheet.getRange(1+rowset3, 1, csvSep2.length, colset).setValues(csvSep2);
    sheet.getRange(1+rowset4, 1, csvOct1.length, colset).setValues(csvOct1);
    sheet.getRange(1+rowset5, 1, csvOct2.length, colset).setValues(csvOct2); 
    sheet.getRange(1+rowset6, 1, csvNov1.length, colset).setValues(csvNov1);
    sheet.getRange(1+rowset7, 1, csvNov2.length, colset).setValues(csvNov2);
    sheet.getRange(1+rowset8, 1, csvDec1.length, colset).setValues(csvDec1);
    sheet.getRange(1+rowset9, 1, csvDec2.length, colset).setValues(csvDec2);
    sheet.getRange(1+rowset10, 1, csvDec3.length,colset).setValues(csvDec3);
```

Comment: I would combine all the parseCsv arrays into one big array using Array concat method then use 1 setValues to write to the sheet https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

Comment: I tried to use this method, but something is off.  It is not writing into my new array.  Any help would be much appreciated:     

var fullarray = []
  fullarray.concat(csvAUG,csvNov1,csvNov2,csvOct1,csvOct2,csvSep1,csvSep2,csvDec1,csvDec2,csvDec3);

Comment: fullarray = fullarray.concat(csvAUG,.....)